# Проблема с вставкой изображения

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, написал скрипт вставки изображения в текстарею, но вставка идет не изображения а его кода. Скажите как сделать так что бы перетягивался в текст арею не код а видимое изображение. Вот сылка на то что сейчас есть http://jsbin.com/ifayof/1/edit .Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `textarea` нельзя отобразить ничего кроме текста. Замените `textarea` на:

```
<div id="drop" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Подробнее о свойстве `contenteditable` можно почитать [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/contenteditable), [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) и [здесь](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/)

Answer (score 1):

textarea НЕ умеет отображать картинки, используйте вместо него div c атрибутом [contenteditable](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/contenteditable)

Comment: опередили немного)